# UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute doesn't forward original querystring on Request

Tags: asp.net-core, system.diagnostics, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm using `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` to render custom error pages and I also have a Anchor TagHelper that needs to look at query string values and this TagHelper is used in `_Layout.cshtml`.  However, when a 'status code' page is being rendered, the original query string values are not passed.

Normally, the TagHelper gets the query string values via:

```
var queryStrings =
    ViewContext?.HttpContext?.Request.Query
        .ToDictionary( d => d.Key, d => d.Value.ToString(), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase );
```

Is there anyway to have the original query string passed so that this code continues to work?

Currently, my work around is to put the following code inside my TagHelper's `Process` method but it seems a bit heavy handed (especially if there are a lot of anchors on the page).

```
// Using UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute removes the querystring from the request
var feature = ViewContext?.HttpContext?.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();
var nvp = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString( feature?.OriginalQueryString ?? "" );
var originalQueryStrings =
    nvp
        .AllKeys
        .ToDictionary( d => d, d => nvp[ d ], StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase );
```

Interestingly, `UseExceptionHandler` seems to pass the original query string values through (unless I haven't traced the code based I'm working with is doing something special which I'm not seeing).

Comment: You can see this [thread](https://andrewlock.net/retrieving-the-path-that-generated-an-error-with-the-statuscodepages-middleware/) may helpful.

Comment: Yes, that is where I figured out how to do my workaround, but just making sure that is appropriate way to handle it in a taghelper.